# Elements in preexisting Python list are disappearing and changing into None

Tags: python, indexing, iteration, nonetype, raspberry-pi4

I am having difficulty with a python project involving iterating over several lists at the same time. I am analyzing data collected from a serial device and iterating over it to make derivative calculations, find peak values, write raw data and results to a csv file, and more. I am not brand new to python or programming in general, but new enough that I may not see easy solutions immediately, so please bear with me.

Here is a portion of my code for context:

```
def processData():
 
    x = elapTime
    y = adcData
    dx = []
    dy = []
    peakTime = []
    peakData = []
    
    cutOff = len(adcData) - 6
    
    for i, (n, m) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
        dx.append(x[i+5] - x[i])
        dy.append(y[i+5] - y[i])        
    
        if i == cutOff:
            break
    
    dx = np.asarray(dx)
    dy = np.asarray(dy)        
    dydx = dy/dx
    der = dydx.tolist()
    
    oneZero = dydx
    oneZero = np.where(oneZero >= 0, 1, oneZero)
    oneZero = np.where(oneZero < 0, 0, oneZero)
    oneZero = oneZero.tolist()
    
    definedPeak = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
    
    for j, (a, b, c, d) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(x, y, der, oneZero)):
        if c > 3:
            chunk = oneZero[j:j+11]
            if chunk == definedPeak:
                peakTime.append(x[j+9])
                peakData.append(y[j+9])
             
    
 with open(fileName, 'w',) as testfile:
        wr = csv.writer(testfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerows(itertools.zip_longest(elapTime,
                                           adcData,
                                           der,
                                           oneZero,
                                           peakTime,
                                           peakData))
```

And here is the part giving me trouble:

```
for j, (a, b, c, d) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(x, y, der, oneZero)):
    if c > 3:
        chunk = oneZero[j:j+11]
        if chunk == definedPeak:
            peakTime.append(x[j+9])
            peakData.append(y[j+9])
```

When I run this code on my Raspberry Pi 4 I get this error on the if statement asking if 'c' is greater than 3:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

My expectations for this entire block of code is that it returns to me the raw time and data I collected from my serial device, the derivative values I calculated, the 'oneZero' list where each of the derivative values were changed to a one or zero, and the specific locations of peaks in the data. I have defined what a peak should look like and as long the rolling window I created of the oneZero list matches my predefined peak list, then I will save the time and data value in respective lists.

This code was all stable and functional until I added this line:

```
if c > 3:
```

I used a print statement within the corresponding for loop to see what could be causing the error and saw that the elapTime and adcData lists (which have existed before I called the processData() funcion) had at some arbitrary time lost the recorded values they had and were all replaced by 'None.'

Even though removing the if statement returns my program to a stable and functional state, I need a condition like this since it will filter out any noise in the derivatives I am calculating. I appreciate your time and patience with me if I have missed something elementary.

EDIT:

The size of the lists I am using are up to 2000+ entries, and the shortest list I iterate through is only about 5 entries less than the longest one. Until I added the if statement above, all the data I collected was present, but following that line I will notice that I will only have about a few hundred for the same amount of time I run my serial device.

Comment: You are using `zip_longest`, which will fill in any shorter iterable with `None`...

Comment: I know this, however the length of the lists has been a non issue until I added that specific line of code. `zip_longest` has not given me this error before I added `if c > 3:`

Comment: OK, what's your point? `c > 3` would *definitely give you that error if `c` is `None`*

Comment: My point is it should not be a `None` type. I am iterating over thousands of data entries, all of which were `int` prior to this strange error. In this case `c` refers to the derivative list, which is calculated based on two lists of type `int`. This should not be the case, and it seems that I am losing a large amount of data entries per my original quesion and edit.

Comment: Prior to adding the line `if c > 3:` I did not have any errors kick back of this kind. I had a different solution to check for my predetermined peaks and I used a very similar if statement for that solution. That if statement worked fine, but the solution itself was clunky so I scrapped it. The fact that I lose a large amount of data because of this line tells me it does not have to do with the length of the list. Besides, I have used the same for-loop structure for a while without any similar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned in the comments, at least one of the iterables `x, y, oneZero` is longer than `der`, and `zip_longest` will fill the shorter iterables with `None` values to match the length of the longest iterable.

For example

```
list(zip_longest([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b']))
```

will return

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, None), (4, None)]
```

Bulit-in `zip` on the other hand cuts off the longer iterables:

```
list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b']))
```

will return

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

`zip` will also work for multiple iterables, just like `zip_longest`.

---

If you want to skip the `c > 3` check for `None` values you can simply extend it like this:

```
if c is not None and c > 3:
```

But as it is, your program will not do anything once the end of `der` is reached, you will need to define a behaviour for the case `c is None`. If you want to handle `c is None` the same as `c > 3` you should use

```
if c is None or c > 3:
```

If you want the opposite you should just switch `zip_longest` to `zip`.

Comment: `zip` will not work for what I need here since zip will truncate any included lists to match the shortest one available. I was only when I added `if c > 3:` that I started having difficulty with the NoneTypes

Comment: Then you'll need to skip over the values, as outlined in my updated answer

Comment: I cannot currently test your solution since I am away from the hardware I am using, but I will attempt it tomorrow. I should note that these lists have thousands of data points and the shortest list is only about 5 points shorter than the longest list.

Comment: I tried using `zip` first to see if that would work and it did. I am still curious why my data from my longer lists would be deleted, even though I have used this kind of if statement with `zip_longest`. Thank you for your help!